# What is difference of customization user model between AbstractBaseUser and AbstractUser

Tags: django, django-authentication

I want to extend and customize built-in django user model. The main reason of customization is that i want to do email field as unique identifier of all users and also i need to add some extrafields to every user. While reading docs i found several solutions to achieve my goal. One of them require inherite from `AbstractBaseUser`

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
   pass
```

And another solution require to inherite from `AbstractUser`

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

But i didn't understood what is difference of inheritance between AbstractBaseUser and AbstractUser

Comment: If any answer serves your purpose, please mark as `Accepted` so that other people could be benefited from the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Django uses authentication using `username` field by default. If you want to use an `email` address as your authentication instead of a `username`, then it is better to extend `AbstractBaseUser`. But, if you are happy with how django handle authentication but need some extra information on `User` model, then you can extend `AbstractUser`.

Extending `AbstractBaseUser` gives you full control over `User` model.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
     email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
     first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
     last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
     date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
     is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True)
     avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', null=True, blank=True)

     objects = UserManager()

     USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
     REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Extending `AbstractUser` gives you an opportunity to add extra information on top of Django's default `User` model. Although, you can set `username = None` and  `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` at extended `User` model, if you need full control over User model, choose `AbstractBaseUser`.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
     father_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
     address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
     birth_date = models.DateField()
```

Comment: According your explanation extending User based on AbstractUser the same as extending based on OneToOneField ?

Comment: if your explanation is right than this tutorial is uncorrect https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/

Comment: Its clearly stated in the docs, `AbstractBaseUser` give you full control in the model, use it when you have many changes and you don't like the default `User` model, or if you love the way django handles auth, and you just want to add some fields, use `AbstractUser` which give you the default `User` model in abstract form.

Comment: Although, by extending AbstractUser, you can set `username = None` and  `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`, if you need full control over User model, choose `AbstractBaseUser`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: thanks for your answer. but your words is not clear enough. when you say "Although, by extending AbstractUser, you can set username = None and USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'", it is meant that abstractuser is enough for that goal. so why is it better to user abstractbaseuser.