# Should I use "AbstractUser" or "AbstractBaseUser"? (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, abstract-class, django-authentication

My requirement is to create AUTH system which uses email as AUTH token and some extra fields like name, phone etc and get rid of username field:

I can achieve this using both the abstract classes ! But confused on which to use

```
I can just use AbstractUser and make "username=None" and then add usernanager ! 
Or should i use AbstractBaseUser and redo everything ?
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59583231/what-is-difference-of-customization-user-model-between-abstractbaseuser-and-abst) answer exaplains it better which one to use. However it depends on a lot of things. In short :

> Django uses authentication using username field by default. If you
> want to use an email address as your authentication instead of a
> username, then it is better to extend AbstractBaseUser. But, if you
> are happy with how django handle authentication but need some extra
> information on User model, then you can extend AbstractUser.

You also can check the documentation [Using a custom user model when starting a project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) .

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you better use **"AbstractUser" class** instead of **"AbstractBaseUser" class**. Actually, using **"AbstractUser" class** or **"AbstractBaseUser" class**, you can do the same things such as adding and removing fields and so on. And actually, **"AbstractUser" class** is **the subclass of "AbstractBaseUser" class** and **"AbstractUser" class** has **11 fields** which you will basically use as shown below:

```
id
password
last_login
is_superuser
username
first_name
last_name
email
is_staff
is_active
date_joined
```

But **"AbstractBaseUser" class** which is **the superclass of "AbstractUser" class** only has **3 fields** which you will basically use as shown below:

```
id
password
last_login
```

So, when you create **"CustomUser" class** with **"AbstractUser" class**, you can write **much less code** defining less fields because **"AbstractUser" class** already has **8 more fields** which you will basically use than **"AbstractBaseUser" class**.

For example, you want to log in with **"email"** and **"password"** instead of **"username"** and **"password"** so you create **2 "CustomUser" classes** with **"AbstractUser" class** and **"AbstractBaseUser" class** as shown below:

### <**"AbstractUser" class**>

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from .managers import CustomUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None # Remove "username"
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "custom user"
        verbose_name_plural = "custom users"
```

### <**"AbstractBaseUser" class**>

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils import timezone
from .managers import CustomUserManager

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField("first name", max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField("last name", max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        "staff status",
        default=False,
        help_text="Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.",
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        "active",
        default=True,
        help_text=
            "Designates whether this user should be treated as active. "
            "Unselect this instead of deleting accounts."
        ,
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField("date joined", default=timezone.now)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    objects = CustomUserManager() # Here
```

As you can see above, **"CustomUser" class** with **"AbstractUser" class** has **much less code** than the one with **"AbstractBaseUser" class**. That's why basically, you better use **"AbstractUser" class** instead of **"AbstractBaseUser" class**.

Answer (score 0):

according to [[Django Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user):

> If you’re entirely happy with Django’s User model, but you want to add some additional profile information, you could subclass `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` and add your custom profile fields, although we’d recommend a separate model as described in the “Model design considerations” note of Specifying a custom user model. `AbstractUser` provides the full implementation of the default User as an abstract model.

So i think you are not happy with `AbstractUser` and you want something different. so just use `AbstractBaseUser` and extend it as you wish.